# rails doesn't load all attributes in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, amazon-web-services, carrierwave

I use Rails as a backend and React as a frontend.

I upload photos of meals via [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to my [AWS S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_FR&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CStorage%7CS3%7CFR%7CEN%7CText&sc_content=s3_e&sc_detail=aws%20s3&sc_category=Storage&sc_segment=293644153832&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=FR&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!293644153832!e!!g!!aws%20s3&ef_id=Cj0KCQiAlIXfBRCpARIsAKvManxb7L3G3ddqXc7khAsrcstIGCFzLLG563QOiD6cCPJ-1Ua-xHuy8IQaAn_zEALw_wcB:G:s).

When I do so, here is what I get from the rails console:

```
m = Meal.first
[...]
m.photo
=> #<PhotoUploader:0x007fef8e4381b0 @model=#<Meal id: 1, name: "Burger Caviar", price: "5.99", original_price: "8.90", description: "Delicieux Burger, parfume au caviar d'aubergine et...", ingredients: "Pain, steack de boeuf, caviar, salade, tomates, oi...", allergenes: "aucun", category: "Français", week_day: 1, photo: "Photo_May_21_11_45_12_PM_1024x1024.jpg", vacation_mode: false, restaurant_id: 1, created_at: "2018-11-06 13:00:46", updated_at: "2018-11-06 13:00:46">, @mounted_as=:photo, @file=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x007fef8e433c50 @uploader=#<PhotoUploader:0x007fef8e4381b0 ...>, @base=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x007fef8e433ea8 @uploader=#<PhotoUploader:0x007fef8e4381b0 ...>>, @path="uploads/Photo_May_21_11_45_12_PM_1024x1024.jpg", @content_type=nil>, @filename=nil, @cache_id=nil, @versions={}, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog:0x007fef8e433ea8 @uploader=#<PhotoUploader:0x007fef8e4381b0 ...>>>

m.photo.path
=> "uploads/Photo_May_21_11_45_12_PM_1024x1024.jpg"

m.photo.url
=> "https://take-a-meal-images.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/Photo_May_21_11_45_12_PM_1024x1024.jpg"
```

I actually need `m.photo.path` to serve my image (via [imgix](https://github.com/imgix/react-imgix)) to the client in React. 
However, when I call my meals via [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and `console.log` the response, all I get is the photo URL:

```
data: Array(9)
[...]
0:
  created_at: "2018-11-06T14:00:49.373+01:00"
  id: 10
  name: "Burger Nordiste"
  photo:
      url: "https://take-a-meal-images.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/header-image.jpg"
[...]
```

My `controllers/meals_controller.rb`:

```
class MealsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @meals = Meal.all
    render json: @meals.to_json(include: :restaurant)
  end
end
```

so why does rails only serve `photo.url` and how can I change that in order to access `photo.path` in React ?

Comment: It looks like carrierwave specifically exports the url[1]. You'll likely need to create a new serializer to include additional attributes. [1]: https://git.io/fpvx6

Comment: Hi @BaylorRae', thank you very much for your help. I actually do not really understand what a serializer is and in my case how I can solve my issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to override the default serializer for an uploader is to overload the `serializable_hash` method inside your uploader.

> If this is an overload you need to apply often I would recommend creating a module/concern to avoid duplication.

```
# app/uploaders/photo_uploader.rb
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # existing code...

  def serializable_hash(*args)
    super(*args).merge({'path': path})
  end
end
```

Comment: sometimes, heros don't wear capes.